# How to use the SQL similar syntax to find out what SI_USERNAME is being used to access a UNC path in Crystal Reports 2008 / SAP?

Tags: crystal-reports

In a webapp I found in an old `Crystal Reports Server 2008` installation, I tried connecting with MySQL and was met with a lot of `varbinary` fields that have pretty strange content and require some sort of [custom codepage](http://pinchii.com/2010/09/decoding-the-crystal-reports-server-2008-database-cms_infoobjects6/) to be read.

After some googling I determined that there is an administrator interface lurking in the Tomcat webapps directory, and I was able to access a web app called `Business Objects Business Intelligence platform - Query Builder` and it has an SQL-like syntax (not sure what it is called, seems kinda SAP related)... but the results that come back from it are nested and strange.

```
SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_NAME like '<name-of-scheduled-cr-report>'
```

And it returns a massive result, even just for the one job I was looking for...it appears to have nested records as well, and within them there are domain usernames for accessing things like shares...(see below):

[image]

I really only want to access `SI_NAME` and `SI_USERNAME` but I don't understand how to query it; it almost looks like it's in another table or something.

Comment: I'm thinking there might be additional usernames in there too...for databases and such...I'd really like to know how to query the sub objects considering this isn't json and it isn't sql exactly.

Comment: I know nothing about the schema below the MySQL database; it almost seems like it might have an object database stored in some of the records, and this tool allows you to query that.